# finding the phone number whose digits sum to the largest number in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first time using Ruby and i need to take an array with three 10 digits phone numbers and have the program give me the phone number whose sum is the greatest.

my_array = (['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333'])

## => '963-481-7945'

I have no idea where to start.

Please help!

I am currently doing the codeacademy course on Ruby. But so far I don't know enough to get through this problem.

I thought about starting with
my_array = (['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333'])
my_array[2]

which would give me the desired answer of
=> "963-481-7945"

but i know that's not the way to go.

I was thinking so performing a sum for each value and then setting it equal to the set of number I want to display but I'm not sure how to set that up.

Comment: You should start with reading your course material. Good luck! Let us know how it goes!

Comment: This isn't exactly a tutorial site. Typically, you give it your best go and then come on here asking for more detailed information. Build yourself a hello world Ruby script, move on to having it display a sum of numbers, and go from there.

Comment: It is clearly a homework. Which parts of the language have so far been on your course? Chances are you will be expected to use them. There are some nice methods under `Array` class for sorting, finding maximums etc - what do you know, and do any of them look like a likely start? Giving those details - how you are thinking, what you have tried - is going to help define a useful question. I could give you a one-liner in 30 seconds, but I don't feel that really helps you, other than getting your homework done by a stranger!

Comment: When you download Ruby it should come with a book called "The Book of Ruby". Your answer is within the first 100 pgs.

Comment: No I understand, I definitely want to learn how to do it and not just get an answer. I've done the codeacademy Ruby tutorial about half way thru. I'm still working through it but with what i know so far I can crack this problem.

Comment: Remember, a string (phone number) is just an **array** of letters/numbers.. that's your biggest hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would something like this:

```
my_array = (['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333'])
highest_sum = 0
highest_phone_number = 0

my_array.each do |phone_number|
    sum = phone_number.gsub('-', '').split('').map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+)
    if sum > highest_sum
        highest_sum = sum
        highest_phone_number = phone_number
    end
end

puts highest_phone_number
#=> 963-481-7945
```

You look through each string in the array of phone number strings (my_array) and get the sum of each phone number string. You do this by replacing the dashes ('-') with nothing (''), splitting the phone number string into digits, mapping each digit to an integer, and then summing the digits. Once you get the sum of the phone number, check to see if it is larger than the current highest_sum. If so, set the highest_sum to that sum and the highest_phone_number to the current phone number. After you've looped though all the phone number strings, just output the highest_phone_number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
my_array = (['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333', '222-111-3333'])

sum_arr  = []
sum_hash = {}

my_array.each do |s|
  sum = s.gsub("-","").split(//).inject(0) {|z, x| z + x.to_i}
  puts sum
  sum_hash[sum] = sum_hash[sum] ? sum_hash[sum] << s : [s]
  puts sum_hash.inspect
end

puts sum_hash.max_by { |k,v| k }
```

Part of my solution come from: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_digits_of_an_integer

Note: The question changed between during I wrote my answer :(

Comment: This is what i have so far:

my_array = (['123-456-7777','111-222-3333','963-481-7945'])
sum1 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+7+7+7
puts sum1
sum2 = 1+1+1+2+2+2+3+3+3+3
puts sum2
sum3 = 9+6+3+4+8+1+7+9+4+5
puts sum3

my_array.each do |phone_number|
    sum = phone_number
    if sum = highest_sum
        highest_sum = sum
        highest_phone_number = phone_number
    end
end

puts highest_phone_number
The result is:

49
21
56
963-481-7945
=> nil
i noticed that it only gives me to third set of numbers. 
So there is something wrong there. 
What are your thoughts, any tips to correct this?

Comment: also sorry about the format, i had it all nice and formatted correctly but when i hit enter it changed it to this above. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @DLP2889 You do not perform a sum in your loop you just assign the phone number to sum ! You need to perform the sum. You do `sum = phone_number if sum = highest_sum` ... you do not compare anything just put `highest_sum` into `sum` that return a true value !  Don't know if my explanation is clear. You cannot but code block in comments you need to use the backtick to put inline code.